# Cordova AdMobPro - Not working

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, admob

I have installed all the necessary files on Android SDK. I'm using this code from tutorial:

```
var admobid = {};
    if( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) { // for android & amazon-fireos 
    admobid = {
        //banner: 'ca-app-pub-xxx/xxx', // or DFP format "/6253334/dfp_example_ad" 
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-9609087637503923/1710134090'
    };
} else if(/(ipod|iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) { // for ios 
    admobid = {
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-xxx/zzz', // or DFP format "/6253334/dfp_example_ad" 
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-xxx/kkk'
    };
} else { // for windows phone 
    admobid = {
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-xxx/zzz', // or DFP format "/6253334/dfp_example_ad" 
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-xxx/kkk'
    };
}
if(AdMob)
{
    AdMob.prepareInterstitial( {adId:admobid.interstitial, autoShow:false} );
}
```

Program doesn't work. When tried using with Windows platform rather android it says AdMob not defined.
Also program works when i add

```
 var admob;
```

(But of course admob doesn't work, only rest of program)

Cordova version 6.0.0

cordova-plugin-admobpro 2.11.1 "AdMob Plugin Pro"

**UPDATE**
I finally got program to run on Android Studio and the program runs ok, but still no admob. The only "error" I was able to get out was this:

02-09 00:20:24.225 1193-1237/com.yourname.hello W/PluginManager: THREAD WARNING: exec() call to AdMob.prepareInterstitial blocked the main thread for 57ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().

Along with this:

02-09 00:30:42.381 1193-1233/com.yourname.hello E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44

02-09 00:30:42.394 1193-1233/com.yourname.hello E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0

02-09 00:30:42.431 1193-1233/com.yourname.hello E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)

Please help, I'm trying everything ):

Comment: have you added js files ?

Comment: In my HTML:
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js">   </script> &&

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js">  </script>

Comment: any other js file added including this two ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add Cordova AdMobPro plugins js file.

Copy js file from plugin folder and put it into your js folder.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/AdMob.js"> </script>
```

Hope this will help you !!

Comment: Copy pasted AdMob.js into js folder and added the lines, still nothing :(

Comment: have you added this in index page ?

Comment: no builds fine. was giving some errors before but fixed it by installing some packages in SDK Manager. I'm trying to run it on android studio but that's also being problematic >_>

Comment: Yes, nothing seems to have changed

Comment: how you have given your package name ? is ther any number added in package name ?

Comment: give your package name.

Comment: Is this it?
<widget id="com.yourname.hello" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">

Comment: yes in your widget id their is any number added bcz it also cause a problem while compile the project.

Comment: No :( ---------------

Comment: @jaydroider: It works for me. Thanks! Up-vote from me!

Comment: I'm not sure if this helped or not, though it still doesn't work properly, it works in my android studio. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: please upvote it also if it is helpful to u . thanks in advance.